# Mailhog on kubernetes not accepting connections

Tags: kubernetes

I have a mailhog pod and a mailer service running in Kubernetes. I am on an M1 machine, mailhog/mailhog was not running properly, so I changed it to jcalonso/mailhog, could this be a problem? The mailer service is unable to dial a TCP connection to the mailhog pod. The pod itself is running, and I am able to view the HTTP site with an ingress to port 8025. Here is my mailer service's yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mail-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mail-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mail-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mail-service
          image: "papaya147/mail-service:latest"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          env:
            - name: MAIL_DOMAIN
              value: ""
            - name: MAIL_HOST
              value: "localhost"
            - name: MAIL_PORT
              value: "1025"
            - name: MAIL_ENCRYPTION
              value: "none"
            - name: MAIL_USERNAME
              value: ""
            - name: MAIL_PASSWORD
              value: ""
            - name: FROM_NAME
              value: "John Smith"
            - name: FROM_ADDRESS
              value: "admin@example.com"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mail-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mail-service
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: mail-port
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

And here is the mailhog deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mailhog
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mailhog
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mailhog
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mailhog
          image: jcalonso/mailhog
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1025
            - containerPort: 8025
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mailhog
spec:
  selector:
    app: mailhog
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: mailhog-smtp-port
      port: 1025
      targetPort: 1025
    - protocol: TCP
      name: mailhog-web-port
      port: 8025
      targetPort: 8025
```

While testing with Docker Swarm, these environment variables worked. Below is a screenshot of the pods logs:
[image link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnu7S.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `localhost` to access the `mailhog` service from your `mail-service` pod. You should be using a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the `mailhog` service in your mail-server's `MAIL_HOST` env variable.

FQDN of any service by default is typically in the format: `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. In this case, the FQDN of the mailhog service would be `mailhog.default.svc.cluster.local` or simply `mailhog.svc.cluster.local` since both the pods are in the same namespace (default)

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-aaaa-records